# Unity running in background causing crash in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, unity-game-engine, flutter-android

### When I try to run unity in background using `flutter_unity_widget`, app crashed randomly.  `E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): ABI: 'arm64'

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): Timestamp: 2022-12-02 14:52:49+0530
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): pid: 7094, tid: 7444, name: UnityMain  >>> com.exmaple.app <<<
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): uid: 10157
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x319
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094): Cause: null pointer dereference
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x0  0000000000000001  x1  0000007130000010  x2  0000000000000001  x3  00000071ac8229a3
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x4  000000000000017a  x5  000000000010c242  x6  731f64716e6c1f6c  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x8  0000000000000001  x9  7a554df95e9d0d6c  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x12 000000752528acc0  x13 00000000000000c1  x14 000000752528ad70  x15 0000006f89f93da5
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x16 00000071aca77950  x17 0000007865c48ebc  x18 0000000000000000  x19 00000071acaa36c0
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x20 b4000071c69c4aa0  x21 00000071acaa3768  x22 0000000000000063  x23 00000071aca92890
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x24 0000000000000010  x25 0000000000000018  x26 0000000000000018  x27 00000071aca940c6
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     x28 0000000000000018  x29 0000000000003234
E/AndroidRuntime( 7094):     sp  000000752528c6c0  lr  00000071ac1825cc  pc  00000071ac182614`
```

Reason for running unity in the background: We have to initiate some SDKs on unity, and that takes time, it takes time for these initialisations, so to resolve this we initiated unity before using it so that all the SDKs must be initialised and we can save some time.

**Previously It was working fine** when we are not using unity in the background.